# Convert PaperKind to PageMediaSizeName

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, system.drawing, system.printing

I manually converted PaperKind to PageMediaSizeName like this:

```
    static PageMediaSizeName ConvertPaperKindToPageMediaSize(PaperKind paperKind)
    {
        switch (paperKind)
        {
            case PaperKind.Custom:
                return PageMediaSizeName.Unknown;
            case PaperKind.Letter:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetter;
            case PaperKind.Legal:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLegal;
            case PaperKind.A4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4;
            case PaperKind.CSheet:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaCSheet;
            case PaperKind.DSheet:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaDSheet;
            case PaperKind.ESheet:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaESheet;
            case PaperKind.LetterSmall:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Tabloid:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloid;
            case PaperKind.Ledger:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Statement:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaStatement;
            case PaperKind.Executive:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaExecutive;
            case PaperKind.A3:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3;
            case PaperKind.A4Small:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.A5:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5;
            case PaperKind.B4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4;
            case PaperKind.B5:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Folio:
                return PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricFolio;
            case PaperKind.Quarto:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaQuarto;
            case PaperKind.Standard10x14:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Standard11x17:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Note:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNote;
            case PaperKind.Number9Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber9Envelope;
            case PaperKind.Number10Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber10Envelope;
            case PaperKind.Number11Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber11Envelope;
            case PaperKind.Number12Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber12Envelope;
            case PaperKind.Number14Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber14Envelope;
            case PaperKind.DLEnvelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISODLEnvelope;
            case PaperKind.C5Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOC5Envelope;
            case PaperKind.C3Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOC3Envelope;
            case PaperKind.C4Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOC4Envelope;
            case PaperKind.C6Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOC6Envelope;
            case PaperKind.C65Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOC6C5Envelope;
            case PaperKind.B4Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4Envelope;
            case PaperKind.B5Envelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOB5Envelope;
            case PaperKind.B6Envelope:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.ItalyEnvelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricItalianEnvelope;
            case PaperKind.MonarchEnvelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaMonarchEnvelope;
            case PaperKind.PersonalEnvelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaPersonalEnvelope;
            case PaperKind.USStandardFanfold:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.GermanStandardFanfold:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaGermanStandardFanfold;
            case PaperKind.GermanLegalFanfold:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaGermanLegalFanfold;
            case PaperKind.IsoB4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4;
            case PaperKind.JapanesePostcard:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcard;
            case PaperKind.Standard9x11:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Standard10x11:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.Standard15x11:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.InviteEnvelope:
                return PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricInviteEnvelope;
            case PaperKind.LetterExtra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterExtra;
            case PaperKind.LegalExtra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLegalExtra;
            case PaperKind.TabloidExtra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloidExtra;
            case PaperKind.A4Extra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4Extra;
            case PaperKind.LetterTransverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.A4Transverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.LetterExtraTransverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.APlus:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.BPlus:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.LetterPlus:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterPlus;
            case PaperKind.A4Plus:
                return PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricA4Plus;
            case PaperKind.A5Transverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.B5Transverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.A3Extra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3Extra;
            case PaperKind.A5Extra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5Extra;
            case PaperKind.B5Extra:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOB5Extra;
            case PaperKind.A2:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA2;
            case PaperKind.A3Transverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.A3ExtraTransverse:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcard:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanDoubleHagakiPostcard;
            case PaperKind.A6:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA6;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku2Envelope;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku3Envelope;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou3Envelope;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou4Envelope;
            case PaperKind.LetterRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterRotated;
            case PaperKind.A3Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3Rotated;
            case PaperKind.A4Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4Rotated;
            case PaperKind.A5Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5Rotated;
            case PaperKind.B4JisRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JISB4Rotated;
            case PaperKind.B5JisRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JISB5Rotated;
            case PaperKind.JapanesePostcardRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcardRotated;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcardRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcardRotated;
            case PaperKind.A6Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.ISOA6Rotated;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku2EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku3EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou3EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou4EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.B6Jis:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JISB6;
            case PaperKind.B6JisRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JISB6Rotated;
            case PaperKind.Standard12x11:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanYou4Envelope;
            case PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.JapanYou4EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.Prc16K:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC16K;
            case PaperKind.Prc32K:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC32K;
            case PaperKind.Prc32KBig:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC32KBig;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber1:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC1Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber2:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC2Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC3Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber4:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC4Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber5:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC5Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber6:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC6Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber7:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC7Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber8:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC8Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber9:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC9Envelope;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC10Envelope;
            case PaperKind.Prc16KRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC16KRotated;
            case PaperKind.Prc32KRotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC32KRotated;
            case PaperKind.Prc32KBigRotated:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber1Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC1EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber2Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC2EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC3EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber4Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC4EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber5Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC5EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber6Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC6EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber7Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC7EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber8Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC8EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber9Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC9EnvelopeRotated;
            case PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10Rotated:
                return PageMediaSizeName.PRC10EnvelopeRotated;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("paperKind");
        }
    }
```

But does anyone have any better idea of how to do this? I use the old Forms print dialogs to get/set printer settigns but want to print a WPF FixedDocument and need to know the Media for the PrintTicket.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the mapping!

For others' benefit, here's the bidirectional mapping as a pair of dictionaries, wrapped up in extension methods:

```
public static class UiExtensions
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<PaperKind, PageMediaSizeName> _kindToSizeName;

    private static readonly Dictionary<PageMediaSizeName, PaperKind> _sizeNameToKind =
        new Dictionary<PageMediaSizeName, PaperKind>();

    static UiExtensions()
    {
        _kindToSizeName = new Dictionary<PaperKind, PageMediaSizeName>
            {
                {PaperKind.Custom, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.Letter, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetter}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterSmall, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetter}, 
                {PaperKind.Tabloid, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloid}, 
                {PaperKind.Ledger, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloid}, 
                {PaperKind.Legal, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLegal}, 
                {PaperKind.Statement, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaStatement}, 
                {PaperKind.Executive, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaExecutive}, 
                {PaperKind.A3, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3}, 
                {PaperKind.A4, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4}, 
                {PaperKind.A4Small, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4}, 
                {PaperKind.A5, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5}, 
                {PaperKind.B4, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4}, 
                {PaperKind.B5, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB5Extra}, 
                {PaperKind.Folio, PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricFolio}, 
                {PaperKind.Quarto, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaQuarto}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard10x14, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmerica10x14}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard11x17, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloid}, 
                {PaperKind.Note, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNote}, 
                {PaperKind.Number9Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber9Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.Number10Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber10Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.Number11Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber11Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.Number12Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber12Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.Number14Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaNumber14Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.CSheet, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaCSheet}, 
                {PaperKind.DSheet, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaDSheet}, 
                {PaperKind.ESheet, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaESheet}, 
                {PaperKind.DLEnvelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISODLEnvelope}, 
                {PaperKind.C5Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC5Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.C3Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC3Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.C4Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC4Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.C6Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC6Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.C65Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOC6C5Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.B4Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.B5Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB5Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.B6Envelope, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.ItalyEnvelope, PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricItalianEnvelope}, 
                {PaperKind.MonarchEnvelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaMonarchEnvelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PersonalEnvelope, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaPersonalEnvelope}, 
                {PaperKind.USStandardFanfold, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.GermanStandardFanfold, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaGermanStandardFanfold}, 
                {PaperKind.GermanLegalFanfold, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaGermanLegalFanfold}, 
                {PaperKind.IsoB4, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB4}, 
                {PaperKind.JapanesePostcard, PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcard}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard9x11, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard10x11, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard15x11, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.InviteEnvelope, PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricInviteEnvelope}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterExtra, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterExtra}, 
                {PaperKind.LegalExtra, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLegalExtra}, 
                {PaperKind.TabloidExtra, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaTabloidExtra}, 
                {PaperKind.A4Extra, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4Extra}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterTransverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.A4Transverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterExtraTransverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.APlus, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.BPlus, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterPlus, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterPlus}, 
                {PaperKind.A4Plus, PageMediaSizeName.OtherMetricA4Plus}, 
                {PaperKind.A5Transverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.B5Transverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.A3Extra, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3Extra}, 
                {PaperKind.A5Extra, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5Extra}, 
                {PaperKind.B5Extra, PageMediaSizeName.ISOB5Extra}, 
                {PaperKind.A2, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA2}, 
                {PaperKind.A3Transverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.A3ExtraTransverse, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcard, PageMediaSizeName.JapanDoubleHagakiPostcard}, 
                {PaperKind.A6, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA6}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2, PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku2Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3, PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku3Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3, PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou3Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4, PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou4Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.LetterRotated, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetterRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.A3Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA3Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.A4Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.A5Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA5Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.B4JisRotated, PageMediaSizeName.JISB4Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.B5JisRotated, PageMediaSizeName.JISB5Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapanesePostcardRotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcardRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseDoublePostcardRotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanHagakiPostcardRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.A6Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.ISOA6Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber2Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku2EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeKakuNumber3Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanKaku3EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber3Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou3EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeChouNumber4Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanChou4EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.B6Jis, PageMediaSizeName.JISB6}, 
                {PaperKind.B6JisRotated, PageMediaSizeName.JISB6Rotated}, 
                {PaperKind.Standard12x11, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4, PageMediaSizeName.JapanYou4Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.JapaneseEnvelopeYouNumber4Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.JapanYou4EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc16K, PageMediaSizeName.PRC16K}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc32K, PageMediaSizeName.PRC32K}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc32KBig, PageMediaSizeName.PRC32KBig}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber1, PageMediaSizeName.PRC1Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber2, PageMediaSizeName.PRC2Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3, PageMediaSizeName.PRC3Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber4, PageMediaSizeName.PRC4Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber5, PageMediaSizeName.PRC5Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber6, PageMediaSizeName.PRC6Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber7, PageMediaSizeName.PRC7Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber8, PageMediaSizeName.PRC8Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber9, PageMediaSizeName.PRC9Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10, PageMediaSizeName.PRC10Envelope}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc16KRotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC16KRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc32KRotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC32KRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.Prc32KBigRotated, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber1Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC1EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber2Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC2EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber3Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC3EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber4Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC4EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber5Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC5EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber6Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC6EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber7Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC7EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber8Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC8EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber9Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC9EnvelopeRotated}, 
                {PaperKind.PrcEnvelopeNumber10Rotated, PageMediaSizeName.PRC10EnvelopeRotated}, 
            };

        foreach (var pair in _kindToSizeName)
        {
            _sizeNameToKind[pair.Value] = pair.Key;
        }

        _sizeNameToKind[PageMediaSizeName.Unknown] = PaperKind.Custom;
    }

    public static PageMediaSizeName ToPageMediaSizeName(this PaperKind kind)
    {
        PageMediaSizeName sizeName;
        return _kindToSizeName.TryGetValue(kind, out sizeName) ? sizeName : PageMediaSizeName.Unknown;
    }

    public static PaperKind ToPaperKind(this PageMediaSizeName sizeName)
    {
        PaperKind kind;
        return _sizeNameToKind.TryGetValue(sizeName, out kind) ? kind : PaperKind.Custom;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var sizeName = PaperKind.A4.ToPageMediaSizeName();
Console.WriteLine(sizeName); // ISOA4
```

Answer (score 0):

As far a I know is there no exisiting convert. I would implement the conversion in a more readable version:

```
static Dictionary<PaperKind, PageMediaSizeName> PaperKindMap = new Dictionary<PaperKind, PageMediaSizeName>()  
{
    {PaperKind.Custom, PageMediaSizeName.Unknown},
    {PaperKind.Letter, PageMediaSizeName.NorthAmericaLetter},
    //...
};

static PageMediaSizeName ConvertPaperKindToPageMediaSize(PaperKind paperKind) 
{
    if (PaperKindMap.ContainsKey(paperKind)) {
        return PaperKindMap[paperKind];
    } else {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```